# wxpython wx.combobox save wx.StaticText view help me

Tags: sqlite, wxpython

```
import wx
import sqlite3

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self.panel)

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        self.cursor =  self.conn.cursor()

        self.autoRefersh()

    def autoRefersh(self):
        self.LoadList()
        wx.CallLater(1000, self.autoRefersh)

    def LoadList(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM CLINIC1")
        for date1 in self.cursor: pass
        self.staticText2_1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=date1[1], style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, pos=(100,100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

combobox data sqlite3 save in why panel show Why it looks different bug??
I do not know why this is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one crucial step, getting the data itself.
You are using the cursor object not the data returned by the cursor.

```
def LoadList(self):
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM CLINIC1")
    data = self.cursor.fetchall()
    for date1 in data: pass
    self.staticText2_1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=date1[1], style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, pos=(100,100))
```

AS you are "passing" in your `for loop` perhaps what you actually want is only a single record, in which case

```
data = self.cursor.fetchone()
```

and drop the `for loop`

Even better, read the tutorial

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/python-a-simple-step-by-step-sqlite-tutorial/

In the heading of your question you mention combobox, so I assume that you want to replace the statictext with a combobox. The following should get you started, I'll leave the wx.EVT_COMBOBOX event binding for you to add, as you will need it to do something when you select an item.

```
import wx
import sqlite3

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.selected_data=[]
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.combo = wx.ComboBox(self.panel,-1,choices=self.selected_data, size=(130,30))

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        self.cursor =  self.conn.cursor()
        self.combo.SetValue("Choose an Item")
        self.autoRefresh()

    def autoRefresh(self):
        self.LoadList()

    def LoadList(self):
        self.combo.Clear()
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM CLINIC1")
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for date1 in data:
            self.selected_data.append(date1[1])
        for i in self.selected_data:
            self.combo.Append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Edit:
It should look like this.[image: What is should look like]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply again. I've done it the way you indicated, but I have questions. When I load it with self.autoRefersh (), there will be a text after image on the panel. Is this a bug?

Comment: See my edit as to what it should look like. It may depend on what you have stored in your database table CLINIC1 at item[1]